# Exec Command InsertHTML not Inserting on Right Place on Content Editable Div Tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to insert an image using insertHtml execCommand inside a content editable div. Check the code below.

```js
function createRange(node, chars, range) {
    if (!range) {
        range = document.createRange()
        range.selectNode(node);
        range.setStart(node, 0);
    }

    if (chars.count === 0) {
        range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
    } else if (node && chars.count >0) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            if (node.textContent.length < chars.count) {
                chars.count -= node.textContent.length;
            } else {
                 range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
                 chars.count = 0;
            }
        } else {
            for (var lp = 0; lp < node.childNodes.length; lp++) {
                range = createRange(node.childNodes[lp], chars, range);

                if (chars.count === 0) {
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
   } 

   return range;
}

function setCurrentCursorPosition(chars) {
    if (chars >= 0) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();

        range = createRange(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].parentNode, { count: chars });

        if (range) {
            range.collapse(false);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
        
        document.execCommand('inserthtml', false, '<br><img id="img1" alt="" src="https://assets.justinmind.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/wireframe-examples-web-and-mobile-header.png" style="width:100%;"><br>');
    }
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">item 1<br>item 2<br><br>item 3<br>item 4<br>item 5<br>...</div>
<button id="addImage" type="button" onclick="setCurrentCursorPosition(24)">Add Image</button>
```

As you can see, the image is not being inserted on right place. It is an example, but let's suppose the user will set the caret at position 24 and then add the image. The image should be inserted at after "item 4" part but it is inserting chars before that, which means it is considering html part, not only text, and placing the image in wrong part. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's counting the carriage returns as characters. If you change the cursor position to 29 it will go in exactly the right place.

If you want to see it in action, just run your code snippet, place your cursor before item 1, then press the right arrow key 29 times and you'll be right after item 4

Comment: hey.. I know I could change the position, but I am supposing a user will set the caret position after "item 4" and then add the image.. it is not adding the image at the right place..

Comment: I copied your code to an external html file and it is working as intended. Even though the code snippet you posted isn't working. Very strange.